# Redirect to multiple URLs using Html or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I would like to redirect to multiple URLs from one index.html file

ex:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='url1'" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL='url'" />
```

I know that using "meta" it can only direct once.

If you see the example, from (index.html) will redirect to url1 but after that i need to navigate back to url (index.html) i am trying to add the code within single index.html file.

I do not have page (index2.html) for url1, it is just a link.

Is there any possibility to use javascript to do this or can this done by html. If yes, i would need an suggestion.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, if you are not the host of the page at URL1 you can't navigate back to the page at URL. If you are the host of the page at URL1 you can use another meta tag in the HTML page at URL1 to redirect back to the page at URL.

Another stuff redirect using the Meta tag is not an ideal solution, and it’s discouraged to use at all. Use [javascript instead](https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/#javascript-redirects).

Comment: Since i do not have page for URL1, can i make a copy of index.html (URL) as index2.html and add javascript on both the pages.   function Redirect() { window.location="URL1"; } setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000); . Currently, using window.location=""